# Dynamically created textarea with no .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to allow users to edit the text of a paragraph in a website. I take a paragraph and replace the `<p>` tags with `<textarea>` tags using the `.replaceWith()` function. When I try to take the value of the `textarea`, it returns blank. Here's a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8LBCb/1/).

HTML:

```
<p><a class="edit">Edit</a>I'm going to change this into a textarea field and retrieve the value.</p>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.edit').hide();
    var object = $('p');
    object.on("mouseenter", function() {
        $('.edit').show();
        object.on('click','.edit',function(){
            var oldText = object.text();
            oldText = oldText.substr(4); // Exclude the word 'Edit'
            object.replaceWith($("<textarea>").val(oldText).css("width",object.css('width')).css('height',object.css('height')));
            var value = object.val();
            alert("Value: "+value);
        });
    });
});
```

I'm a programming beginner, so if you have style or implementation tips, feel free to share. This is just my gut reaction to solving the problem; there may be a simpler way to accomplish the same thing.

EDIT: I should also mention that in my website, each paragraph comes from a database table that I'm displaying using an AJAX function. When the user is done editing, he can click a button, and the website will take the new value of the `textarea` field and `UPDATE *table* SET *text*=newText WHERE *text* LIKE oldText;`

Comment: I'm afraid your "p" object doesn't exist after you replace it with the textarea, you will need a new selector to get the value.

Comment: Your `<p>` never had a `.val()` value, it only has a `.text()`. You need to take the `.val()` of the textarea, not of the `object`!

Comment: You usually don't want to bind event handlers **inside of** other event handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just using `contenteditable='true'` instead of changing to a textarea. It will make the `<p>` editable.

Like this:

```
<p contenteditable='true'><a class="edit">Edit</a>
  I'm going to change this into a textarea field and retrieve the value.</p>
```

If you want to make your text area editable when someone clicks 'Edit', you can create a function that sets the `contenteditable` attribute to `true` and then gives focus to the `<p>` element.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it should be working alright now, but one problem I've run into is that sometimes the website automatically saves the html `&nbsp;` instead of just a space, and the database I'm sending to obviously doesn't understand that. The `oldText` variable I'm saving is pulling the `.html()` from the paragraph, not the text (otherwise, it wouldn't include links), so that's why it does the nbsp, but I can't figure out how to get rid of it.

Comment: You can use this to replace all of the `&nbsp` characters in the text: `$('p').text($('p').text().replace(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(160), "g"), ' '))`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not trying to get the value of the `<textarea>`. Your call:

```
object.replaceWith( ... )
```

does not change the value of the variable "object" — it's still the jQuery object for the `<p>` tag, but after that it's out of the DOM.  `<p>` tags don't have a "value" property.

It's almost always a bad idea to set up event handlers inside another event handler (well, an event handler for interaction events anyway).  Event handlers accumulate, so each "mouseenter" event will add *another* "click" handler.

Answer (score 0):

ckersch is right about an easier method being to use `contenteditable`, but if you're looking to a solution for your specific problem, change your selector from this:

```
var value = object.val();
```

To this:

```
var value = $("textarea").val();
```

Full code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.edit').hide();
    var object = $('p');
    object.on("mouseenter", function() {
        $('.edit').show();
        object.on('click','.edit',function(){
            var oldText = object.text();
            oldText = oldText.substr(4); // Exclude the word 'Edit'
            object.replaceWith($("<textarea>").val(oldText).css("width",object.css('width')).css('height',object.css('height')));
            var value = $("textarea").val();
            alert("Value: "+value);
        });
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8LBCb/4/)

There are many ways you could make it more robust, including adding a class or id to your textarea, and then using it to be selected, such as this way:

```
object.replaceWith($("<textarea class='selectMe'>").val(oldText).css("width",object.css('width')).css('height',object.css('height')));
var value = $(".selectMe").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the method replaceWith() wrong. The argument must be a string or a function that returns a string, not a jquery selector. Also, you should place the onclick event outside of the mouseenter event (this is valid for any event, never nest them)

Comment: This is not correct, and the code does in fact work properly as far as that function goes. It's OK to pass a jQuery object to `.replaceWith()` or any of the other jQuery APIs like that.

Comment: It will work if you have just one element of the matched type. If you have several elements on the page, using a jquery selector will lead to a bunch of bugs

Comment: That's just incorrect. It's not a selector - it's an HTML fragment. The jQuery code explicitly checks for that.

Comment: So if you have several different elements (a,div, span) with the class "container" how the replaceWith() is suppose to works?

Comment: Yes - passing a jQuery object to `.replaceWith()` is perfectly fine, so long as the object makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function makeTextarea(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var edit = $(e.currentTarget);
        var parent = edit.parent();
        edit.remove();

        parent.replaceWith('<textarea>' + parent.text() + '</textarea>');
    }

    $('.edit').on('click', makeTextarea);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U57v2/4/

"When the document is ready listen for clicks on .edit class. When clicked store a reference to the parent element (`<p>`) and then remove the edit element. Finally replace the parent element (`<p>`) with a textarea with the contents of the `<p>` element."

Answer (score 0):

ckersh is absolutely right about the `contenteditable`, but if you're looking for a specific answer to your code, there are a few things you could improve.

There are a couple of issues with your code.  First, you're rebinding the `on('click')` handler every time you mouse over the paragraph, so if you mouse over 5 times, you're executing the anonymous function 5 times. You only need to bind the on routine once.  Second, the variable `object` never changes, so when you replace it with a textarea, you need a new selector to get the value.

[I've updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8LBCb/7/) with the enhancements I've mentioned above.  I also added a `mouseleave` event, because I figure you want to hide the "Edit" button when you leave the paragraph.  The updated javascript can be seen below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.edit').hide();
    var object = $('p');

    object.on("mouseenter", function () {
        $('.edit').show();
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
        $('.edit').hide();
    }).on("click", '.edit', function () {
        var oldText = object.text();
        oldText = oldText.substr(4); // Exclude the word 'Edit'
        object.replaceWith($("<textarea>").val(oldText).css("width", object.css('width')).css('height', object.css('height')));
        var value = $("textarea").val();
        alert("Value: " + value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up going with the `contenteditable` approach, but I also changed my event handlers in the way you suggested.